# JS - How to toggle a CSS class only if it alerady has been toggled

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, navbar

I'm trying to build my own responsive mobile navigation. This is my first attempt but I've got pretty far. It works but I have a problem with proper toggling.

This is my code:

```js
 function classToggle() {
      var navigation = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links')
      navigation.forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle('mobile-navigation'));
    }

    document.querySelector('.menu-toggle-button').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
    document.querySelector('.nav-links').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.nav-links {
    display: none;
}

.nav-links li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1.7em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0
}

nav,
.nav-links {
    flex-direction: column;

}

.menu-toggle-button {
    align-self: flex-end;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-navigation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

    /* Navigation */
    .mobile-navigation {
         flex-direction: row;
    }
    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav-links,
    nav {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .nav-links li {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 2.6em;
    }

    .menu-toggle-button {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="brand">
        <p>Logo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-toggle-button">
        <span>|||</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">Risus Baulits</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sodales Vapien</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">Fermentum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">Posuere Risus!</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzJOrG

What I don't understand is how to add the click event to the menu only if it already has a class *mobile-navigation* so the class won't be toggled on bigger screen when the menu is a simple row of links. I don't want to use jQuery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is use CSS media queryto show/Hide the toggle button depending on the viewport size(windows size),
 for instance:

```
//hide the toggle button
.menu-toggle-button {
  display: none
}
//show the toggle button if window size is less than 768 
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   display: block
}
```

in this way the button will not show on desktop as the click event also

Comment: It's not the button causing problems, the links are. Go to https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzJOrG and click any link.

Comment: i see because you have this event listener, juste remove it `document.querySelector('.nav-links').addEventListener('click', classToggle)` you only need and event click on button, but you still need the css part

Comment: If I do that the menu will not collapse after a link will be clicked or touched.